# Node Express pass function results outside of forEach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am attempting to pass results from a forEach function (that needs to be async, but that's a different story) to ejs. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Block.find({}).populate('servers').exec((err, foundBlocks) => {
    if(err){
        req.flash('error', 'Block not found. Please try again.');
        res.redirect('back');
    } else {
        MyDB.find({}, (err, foundDB) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                foundDB.forEach((DB) => {
                    pinger(DB.object, (output) => {
                        if(output){
                            const string = output;
                            DB.status = true
                            console.log(output)
                        } else {
                            DB.status = false;
                        }
                    })
                });
                res.render('settings/index', {
                    blocks: foundBlocks,
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**async/await** does not works with forEach loop because forEach does not wait for the response to finish, using normal for loop is the key,
your code after replacing forEach with for loop should be like this

```
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Block.find({}).populate('servers').exec((err, foundBlocks) => {
    if(err){
        req.flash('error', 'Block not found. Please try again.');
        res.redirect('back');
    } else {
        MyDB.find({}, (err, foundDB) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                for(let DB of foundDB){
                    pinger(DB.object, (output) => {
                        if(output){
                            const string = output;
                            DB.status = true
                            console.log(output)
                        } else {
                            DB.status = false;
                        }
                    })
                });
                res.render('settings/index', {
                    blocks: foundBlocks,
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```